# owin multiple instance and swagger

Tags: c#, owin, swagger-ui

I would like run multiple instance. I'm using the following code

```
var option = new StartOptions();
option.Urls.Add("http://localhost:9000/Foo");
var app = WebApp.Start(option, Startup)

var option2 = new StartOptions();
option2.Urls.Add("http://localhost:9000/Bar");
var app2 = WebApp.Start(option, Startup);

private static void Startup(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
    configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
    configuration.Formatters.Clear();
    configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(configuration);
    configuration.EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API")).EnableSwaggerUi();
}
```

But when I try to open the following URL: http://localhost:9000/Foo/swagger/ui/index#/

I see this message:

> Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:9000/swagger/docs/v1

Answer (score 0):

Swagger take characters until see first `/` and accept it as your host address. You shoul use `RootUrl` property. Your host address is not valid for default swagger configuration.

```
configuration.EnableSwagger(c =>
                            {
                                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API");
                                // you should use this line
                                c.RootUrl(req=> "http://localhost:9000/Foo");
                            }).EnableSwaggerUi();
```

In your case, you have to pass parameter to `Startup` class for which url is used for `RootUrl` or you can split `Startup` class for each app instance.

Another solution is that: you can use baseUrl `http://localhost:9000/` and `http://localhost:9001/` instead of `http://localhost:9000/Foo` `http://localhost:9000/Bar`. In this case, you does not have to change anything else.